# Python - How to remove "" datetime.date "" that is printed with every item of a list contains dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, datetime

**I have CSV files that contain some info with datetime in them. I extracted the datetime and converted it into a date like this:**

```
daily_readings={"Date":[]}
TIME = df.iloc[4,4]
report_date = pd.to_datetime(TIME).date()
if report_date not in daily_readings['Date']:
    daily_readings['Date'].append(report_date)
```

I imported both datetime and time libraries (not sure if i actually need both). When I print the the dictionary `print(daily_readings['Date'])` I get this output: *[datetime.date(2021, 12, 7), datetime.date(2021, 12, 8)]*
Though when I print the variable report_date: `print(report_date)` I get a clean-looking date like this: *2021-12-08*.
So how can I get the dictionary to have the dates as clean as shown?

Answer (score 1):

You print list of datetime.date objects and what you see is the representation of the list elements. Don't print the whole list, but construct a str from list elements:

```
import datetime
spam = [datetime.date(2021, 12, 7), datetime.date(2021, 12, 8)]
print(spam)
print(', '.join(map(str, spam)))
print(', '.join(str(item) for item in spam))
print(', '.join(item.strftime('%d.%m.%Y') for item in spam))
```

output

```
[datetime.date(2021, 12, 7), datetime.date(2021, 12, 8)]
2021-12-07, 2021-12-08
2021-12-07, 2021-12-08
07.12.2021, 08.12.2021
```

or iterate over the list and print elements one by one.

Comment: Ok i iterated over the list, that was more convenient at the time, but will try constructing a string. TY.